# gksu changing my background

Tags: nautilus, desktop-background, taskbar, gksu

Everytime when i use `gksu nautilus` , it keeps changing my background and the taskbar to the default color and background. How can I restore my background and color after using the command?

Comment: I understand that, but still how can i fix that? besides rebooting it

Comment: I have the same problem and would appreciate hearing from someone who knows something about the problem...  (I have had it return back to the normal desktop in the past but I haven't worked out what triggered it.)  This is an annoying behaviour.